# Django admin and MongoEngine ObjectID instead of int()

Tags: django-admin, mongoengine

Small test case is https://github.com/mekanix/djangomongodbtest, I can't seem to get admin page to show up. I login and get "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ObjectId'" exception. Is django admin used with mongoengine at all or do I have to use something like https://github.com/jschrewe/django-mongoadmin? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the handler for admin as well. The Django provided handler `admin.site.urls` does not work with Mongo.

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django_mongoengine import mongo_admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(mongo_admin.site.urls)),
]
```